# In Rails, apply an increment after transaction has been completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users make a transaction, possibly with a coupon code, and at the end the status changes, cart is marked completed, and mailer is being sent. What I'm trying to do is also update the coupon code used with an incremental change. Right now the transaction's order model has the following:

```
class TbCommerce::Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.table_name = 'tb_commerce_orders'
 scope :search, ->(term){ where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }

 belongs_to :cart, :inverse_of => :order, :foreign_key => :tb_commerce_cart_id
 has_many :transactions, :inverse_of => :order, :foreign_key => :tb_commerce_order_id
 has_one :captured_transaction, ->{ captured }, :class_name => 'TbCommerce::Transaction', :foreign_key => :tb_commerce_order_id

 validates_presence_of :cart, :name, :address, :city, :state, :postal, :country
 validates_uniqueness_of :cart
 validates_length_of :address, :maximum => 30
 validates :email, :format => {:with => Authlogic::Regex.email, :message => 'should look like an email address.'}
 before_create :set_invoice_number

 define_callbacks :capture
 set_callback :capture, :after, :after_capture

 def description
  return cart.description
end

module Status
OPEN = 'open'
PLACED = 'placed'
SHIPPED = 'shipped'
REFUNDED = 'refunded'
REMOVED = 'deleted'
end

def full_name
 return name
end

def full_address
 return "#{address}, #{city} #{state}, #{postal}, #{country}"
end

private

def set_invoice_number
  new_invoice_number = TbCommerce::Order.maximum(:invoice_number) || 1000000
loop do
  new_invoice_number += 1
  break unless TbCommerce::Order.exists?(:invoice_number => new_invoice_number)
end
self.invoice_number = new_invoice_number
end

def after_capture
  update_attribute(:status, Status::PLACED)
  cart.update_attribute(:is_completed, true)
  coupon.update(:used => used + 1)
  TbCommerce::OrderMailer.order_placed(self).deliver_later
  TbCommerce::OrderMailer.order_confirmation(self).deliver_later
  begin
    TbCommerce.after_capture.call(self)
  rescue e
    logger.error "Failed to run the after_capture hook with message: #{e}"
  end
   return true
  end

 end
```

It's the line in after_capture = coupon.update(:used => used + 1). It's not actually incrementing. I've also tried doing @coupon.update(:used => used + 1) and TbCommerce::Coupon.increment_used(self) then in the model having:

```
class TbCommerce::Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :ordered, ->{ order('created_at desc') }
   scope :search, ->(term){ where('code LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }

   validates :code, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
   attr_accessor :skip_api_post

 def increment_used
  update(:used => used + 1)
end

end
```

No failures but not incrementing.

Edit:

Checking the code in my show that has the following:

```
<% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
 <%= coupon.code %>
 <%= coupon.used %>
<% end %>
```

Additional Edit: I have tried all of the following and none of them work or actually trigger binding pry:

```
increment_coupon_used!
binding.pry
update(:used => used + 1)
binding.pry
update_attribute(:used => used + 1)
binding.pry
update_attribute(used: @coupon.used + 1)
binding.pry
TbCommerce::Coupon.increment!(:used)
binding.pry
TbCommerce::Coupon.update(:used => used + 1)
binding.pry
update(used: @coupon.used + 1)
binding.pry
@coupon.increment!(:used)
binding.pry
Coupon.update(:used => used + 1)
binding.pry
```

increment_coupon_used! is actually the following:

```
def increment_coupon_used!
 coupon.increment_used! if coupon.present?
return true

def increment_used!
 update(:used => used + 1)
end
```

Last(?) Update:
Looks like the logger has the error I'm getting. NoMethodError: undefined method `increment!' on @coupon.increment!(:used) and even TbCommerce::Coupon.increment!(:used)

Comment: does the `coupon.update(:used => used + 1)` return true?

Comment: It's possible I'm missing something, but if you want to access the current value of `:used`, you have to save it in a variable, or pass it in like `update(used: @coupon.used + 1)`.

Comment: Tried that @PatMellon.

Comment: @dbugger it does return true

Comment: then it is updating. so either you are either: a) supplying the wrong value; b) updating it again in `after_capture`; or c) looking at the wrong coupon object.  How are you determining it hasn't been incremented?

Comment: I'm checking it against my admin > index view. Edited code to show my view that's drawing on used attribute

Comment: Does it work if you use `after_save :after_capture` instead of `define_callbacks :capture`
 `set_callback :capture, :after, :after_capture` ?

Comment: Gave that a shot @PatMellon. End up with SystemStackError (stack level too deep)

Comment: Be aware of `update(used: self.used +1)` as you may introduce race conditions, and you should look into counting atomically with sql `UPDATE c = c + 1 WHERE id = 123` instead.

Comment: The SystemStackError might be related to the `begin` block in `after_capture`. If you take that block out of the method, it should at least update one record after it's saved. Then maybe you can determine what's going on with the block.

Comment: SystemStackError with removing begin and using after_capture instead of define_callbacks and set_callback

Comment: How does `coupon.update(:used => used + 1)` not crash? Does your order have column `used`? If yes, it will be used, not coupon's `used`. If not, it will crash.

Comment: "NoMethodError: undefined method `increment!' " - you forgot the last, most important part of this exception's message. The object.

Comment: Actually, I don't even see how order is related to coupon. If there is, indeed, no relationship from Order to Coupon, that after callback will crash on resolving the name `coupon`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so it doesn't really look like order and coupon actually have a relationship but I thought I could use the method of increment_used! that's created from the coupon model. Is there a cleaner/simpler way to apply the increment to an instance of the coupon that's being updated?

Comment: @Jake: can be done in a thousand different ways. First thing you have to do is actually get ahold of a coupon instance. If you have a code, maybe something like this: `Coupon.where(code: coupon_code).first.increment!(:used)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So couple of issues were present. The first is that there was a relationship and I wasn't hitting it correctly. What I ended up doing was:

```
cart.increment_coupon_used!
```

Cart actually included the ValidatesCoupon model that has the relationship for the order.

The other problem that is present is that the local app was overriding this gem. So it was never going to work until I included on the cart model.

Comment: Congrats on figuring this out.